# Как реализовать прерывание цикла

Tags: c++, циклы

Как реализовать условие выхода(ввод отрицательного значения при вводе оценки) из цикла, но так чтобы это введеное отрицательное значение не отражалось на расчете на средней оценке ? А также добавить в расчет так чтобы средняя оценка считалась дележкой суммы балов не на пять, а на количество введенных оценок?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

std::cout << "Math's score' " << i+1 << ": ";
std::cin >> scores[i];
if(scores[i]<0)
break;

sum += scores[i];
}

student.set_scores(scores);

float average_ball = sum / 5.0;
```

Comment: Вместо std::cin >> scores[i] введите временную переменную с временем жизни ограниченным циклом, и читайте значение в неё. Так ничего не попадёт в ваш массив, и не испортит расчётов.

Comment: Для количества введённых оценок используйте ещё один счётчик, делов то...

Answer (score 3):

Это не самостоятельный ответ, а скорее добавление к ответу @МишаковМаксим - можно немного наэкономить на переменных :)

```
double average_ball;
for (int i = 0, sum = 0;;) {
    std::cout << "Math's score' " << ++i << ": ";
    int score;
    std::cin >> score;
    if(score < 0)
    {
        average_ball = double(sum)/(i-1);
        break;
    }
    sum += score;
}
cout << average_ball << endl;
```

(увы, в комментарий не втискивается...)

Comment: В таком случае удалю свой ответ

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Зачем? ваш ответ совершенно верный; мой - не более чем уточнение/дополнение...

Comment: Хотя да, те, кто сюда зайдут, смогут увидеть разные реализации и сделать свои выводы

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

std::cout << "Math's score' " << i+1 << ": ";
int score;
std::cin >> score;
if(score < 0)
    break;
scores[i] = score;
sum += score;
count++;
}

student.set_scores(scores);

float average_ball = sum / count;
```

Comment: ...чтобы средняя оценка считалась дележкой суммы балов не на пять, а на количество введенных оценок...

Comment: @АртёмОконечников не дочитал вопрос, добавил

Comment: При вводе первого отрицательного значения вы получите исключение деления на 0